# Derivation of equation of changing inclination of an orbit

Tags: trigonometry

I was researching and found the equation online that shows
$$\Delta v=2v\sin (\frac{\theta}{2}) $$
from my own try on deriving the equation I got
$$\Delta v=\frac{v\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\frac{180-\theta}{2})} $$
I am quite sure that they are equivalent, but I don't know how to prove it and show that they are equivalent. I feel like I am missing something very obvious...How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINTS:

$\sin( \theta )= 2 \sin (\theta /2) \cos( \theta /2)$

$\sin(90- \theta /2) = \cos (\theta /2)$

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @S.chong you are welcome